# How to install freenx on a VPS machine?

Tags: gnome, 13.10, gui, freenx

I've installed VNC before and was really bad so I decided to leave VNC and go to NX but the problem it's I don't know how to install the NX-server on my VPS machine also don't know how to connect remotely to the machine so anyone can tell me the best/correct way to install freenx?

Note: I'm not on an OS complete system, it's just a vps machine (PuTTy)
Also I'm trying to connect from windows OS

Thanks

Comment: here's how to use putty http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CZphjhQxIQ and if you cant connect to ssh, the probably you dont have it, login to vpn as you did before and follow this tutorial http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-linux-install-openssh-sshd-server/ your username will probably be `root`

Comment: I know how to use putty I meant how to connect to the freeNX graphical system from windows. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to add the freenx-team PPA for Ubuntu 12.04 GNU/Linux.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
```

Next, update your sources list, then install the FreeNX server software

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install freenx
```

Next, as noted in the community documentation for installing FreeNX - download the missing nxsetup script, untar it, then copy it to /usr/lib/nx (the command below is one entire line that runs 3 commands and ends with /usr/lib/nx):

```
wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/freenx-server/+bug/576359/+attachment/1378450/+files/nxsetup.tar.gz && tar xvf nxsetup.tar.gz && sudo cp nxsetup /usr/lib/nx
```

Now, run the nxserver setup script.

```
sudo /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup --install --setup-nomachine-key
```

At this point, you have FreeNX server installed, but now you'll want to configure the FreeNX server to configure clients to use ubuntu-2d session:

```
echo -e "\n#Use unity 2d for client sessions\nCOMMAND_START_GNOME='gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d'"|sudo tee -a /etc/nxserver/node.conf
```

[image]

Next, restart the FreeNX server to ensure it takes in the .conf file:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/freenx-server restart
```

That's it for the FreeNX server, now let's move on to the client. First, install the 'qtnx' package on Ubuntu 12.04 so we can have a client application to access the FreeNX server. You'll have to launch the Ubuntu Software Center, then click 'Edit > Software Sources' from the top menu. Then place a check by "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe).

Now, run the commands to update your sources and install the qtnx application from the terminal (CTRL + ALT + t):

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install qtnx
```

from the Dash start the 'qtnx' application. Enter the username/password for a user on the server, set the speed to LAN, then click configure. On the configuration dialog, set a name for the prfile, the hostname(or IP address) for the FreeNX server machine, the client resolution (I used 1024x768), network speed (LAN), and set the platform type to GNOME 
[image]

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX
[more information](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2012/05/how-to-install-freenx-on-ubuntu-1204.html)

EDIT: to connect to VPS machine you can ssh or use [putty](http://putty.ar.softonic.com/) easily.

After you’ve opened Putty, fill out the Hostname or IP Address field with your Hostname or IP Address. The default port for this is 22.

Click on the Open button to open a new command line window.

[image]

When the command line window appears, you will be asked for the SSH username at the login as prompt. Type it in and then press Enter on your keyboard.

[image]

In the command line window, you will also be asked for the SSH password at the login as prompt. Type it in and then press Enter on your keyboard.

[image]

You are now successfully logged into your VPS server using SSH access.

[image]

Comment: Mr. maythux

Thanks for your detailed answer, really appreciate your help but there's another question you might answer on it?

How to connect to the VPS machine from windows not linux.

Thanks

Comment: @user249106 please ask a new question and don't forget to upvote (and maybe accept) a helpful answer.

Comment: @user249106 Please check the edit